# MYSQL and TOP usage in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, select

Does MYSQL allow for the use of TOP in the select statement?

```
SELECT TOP 2 id
From product
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL it's called `LIMIT` and goes near the end of the query:

```
SELECT id
FROM product
LIMIT 2
```

Manual: [SELECT statement, LIMIT clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#idm44810222671920)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL equivalent to TOP is LIMIT.

So your query would be

```
SELECT ID FROM PRODUCT LIMIT 2
```